# Bluesnap’s Payment API: What attributes need to be passed in the Bluesnap request header?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing, bluesnap

I am using Bluesnap’s Payment API to integrate with the Bluesnap gateway. What attributes need to be passed in the Bluesnap request header and for what purpose?

Answer (score 1):

*This is one of the common questions BlueSnap receives. We are sharing the answer here to help other developers who are integrating with BlueSnap.*

For the Bluesnap Payment API, each request header should have the following attributes:

- Basic Authentication- Authorization: Basic {Base64 encoding of
  'username:password'}. username:password are used by Bluesnap to
  authenticate and authorize the API call. You need to get these
  credentials from the Bluesnap merchant console under the “Bluesnap
  API” section.
- Content-Type: application/xml
- bluesnap-version: 2.0

More information can be found here: http://developers.bluesnap.com/docs/authentication